# Why is Spark running slower than Python with large files?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I know that one of the main reasons to use Apache Spark is to make things faster than doing it "manually" with a Python function.

However, I have this file called `bigger_file.txt` with 2.7GB in it, and I want to count the number of times a certain word (let's say the word "word") appears. I did the following using Pyspark.

```
From Pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
rdd = sc.textFile('bigger_file.txt')
rdd.filter(lambda x: 'word' in x).count()
```

This process takes around 40 seconds in my computer. It has an Intel i7 6700 processor with 16GB RAM. I'm using Ubuntu, but I also tried it with Windows and Spark goes extremely slow in Windows for me for some reason.
On the other hand, if I simply do it with Python like this:

```
num = 0
with open('bigger_file.txt') as f:
   for line in txt:
       if 'word' in line:
          num += 1
```

Then the process takes around 10 seconds.

I'm sure it has to do with the number of partitions or executors I need to have, but I'm starting with Spark and I'm not sure what would be the optimal way to configure this, and it doesn't matter the configuration I try, the time it takes for Spark seems to be pretty much the same.

So anyway, the question is: what exactly should I do to Spark to make it process the data faster? Specially with Windows, where it took around 40 minutes to process all this data, when just using Python takes a few seconds. It seems to me I'm doing something wrong, because otherwise I don't see the reason to use Spark.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CPU speed doesn't do anything if your harddrive is slow. Loading 2.7 GB can take a few seconds if the disk is slow, and if you executed the code snippets on different operating systems, don't forget that Windows IO is significantly slower than Linux IO. (https://superuser.com/a/1124517). Also, `f.read()` doesn't return lines - it returns bytes. Use `readLines()` instead. You should also compare the counts to verify that it's actually doing something - can't speak for Spark, but the Python code doesn't work and might do less overall work. Try fixing that and check again

Comment: spark in standalone is pretty useless. it should be used on a cluster. Standalone version is just for sandbox, trying stuff, not for production.

Comment: Spark is optimized for parallelism, even if you have a single file there is still significant overhead.

Comment: Yeah @Zoe, I just realized that I typed my Python code wrongly. I didn't have access to my code when I typed it, so I just did it manually from memory. The code actually did work correctly, and I was getting the same result with both, but I'm still not sure why it works faster with Python than with Spark.